# React Native + Redux new reducer doesn't exist until i reinstall the app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, mobile, react-redux

I have a React Native project that uses Redux as an  When i add a new reducer in my code i need to reinstall the app to see the changes. Anybody knows what is happening?

I am also using Redux-Persist and AsyncStorage in the project. I think the problem may come from these because i didnt have this problem in other projects i worked for. I dont have a code to show because i dont know exactly what is causing this and its not an error so i cant find its source.

This is my reducer:

```
export const initialState = {
  dontShow: false,
};

export const {actions, reducer} = createSlice({
  name: 'feed/news',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    set: state => {
      state.dontShow = true;
    },
  },
});

const dontShowNews = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch(actions.set());
};

export const news = (rootState: RootState): boolean => {
  return rootState.feed.news.dontShow
}
```

Then, in my component im using this

```
  const dontShowNews = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.feed.news.dontShow);

  const MainStack = () => {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator
   initialRouteName={dontShowNews ? "Feed" : "News"}
        headerMode="none">
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Feed"
          component={FeedStack}
        />
       <Stack.Screen
          name="News"
          component={NewsStack}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    );
  };
```

and it gives me this error

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'state.feed.news.dontShow')

**The only way i find to fix this is by reinstalling the app!**

Thanks everyone!

Comment: your question is not understandable, please provide more details about your problem/ issue and consider sharing with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, any useful information.

Comment: please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.  good luck 

Comment: after you make a new reducer, go to store.js and hit ctrl + s